# How can I return a variable and not the numeric value of the variable?

Tags: c++

I want to be able to return `seconds`, `earthDistance`, and `moonDistance` rather than returning their associated number. If I were to output seconds into a different function, then it won't register seconds as a variable.

I have to use the functions given to me. I am not allowed to change them whatsoever. I have to work with what I have.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

double readSeconds()
{
    double seconds;
    cout << "Enter the time (in seconds) ";
    cin >> seconds; //I'm inputting seconds' but it isn't registering to the other function
    while (seconds < 0)
    {
        cout << "The time must be zero or more" << endl;
        cout << "Enter the time (in seconds) ";
        cin >> seconds;
    }
    return seconds; //return seconds doesn't return actually return seconds.
}

double calculateEarthDistance(double seconds)
{
    double gravityEarth = 9.8;
    double earthDistance = 0.5 * gravityEarth * pow(seconds, 2);
    return earthDistance; //same for earthDistance. I return it but isn't 
    registered by other function
}

double calculateMoonDistance(double seconds)
{
    double gravityMoon = 1.6;
    double moonDistance = 0.5 * gravityMoon * pow(seconds, 2);
    return moonDistance;
}

void displayResults (double seconds, double earthDistance, double moonDistance)
{
    cout << "The object traveled " << fixed << setprecision(4) << earthDistance << " meters in " 
    << setprecision(2) << seconds << "seconds on Earth" << endl;
    cout << "The object traveled " << fixed << setprecision(4) << moonDistance << " meters in " 
    << setprecision(2) << seconds << "seconds on the Moon" << endl;
}

int main()
{
    double seconds, earthDistance, moonDistance;
    //part of the assignment is to keep all the functions untouched.
    readSeconds();
    calculateEarthDistance(seconds);
    calculateMoonDistance(seconds);
    displayResults(seconds, earthDistance, moonDistance);
}
```

This is what it should look like:

> Enter the time (in seconds)
>
> The time must be zero or more
>
> Enter the time (in seconds)
>
> The object traveled 540.2250 meters in 10.50 seconds on Earth
>
> The object traveled 88.2000 meters in 10.50 seconds on the Moon

Comment: The statement `readSeconds()` in `main()` discards the value returned by that function - it doesn't magically copy that value to the variable `seconds` in `main()` since the variable named `seconds` in `main()` is a distinct variable entirely from the variable named `seconds` in `readSeconds()`.     Change that statement in `main()` to `seconds = readSeconds()` to fix.    Same comment for other functions.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to be able to return seconds, earthDistance, and moonDistance rather than returning its associated number.

No, you want to return the "associated number" (more commonly called the value of the variable). The problem you are facing is that you need to get those values into the variables of the same name in your main function. (The variable called "seconds" in `readSeconds()` is a different variable than the one called "seconds" in your main function. Same name, but different things.) To do that, you need to assign the value.

For example:

```
    seconds = readSeconds();
```

Similarly for the other functions and variables.